# Getting 400 error while trying to get access token through url in android

Tags: android, android-volley

I am working with `oauth2` and using `Volley` networking library in android. I am trying to get access token by using below code. But I getting 400 Bad request as my response. What is wrong in my request ? I even tried putting content type as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but still no luck. What can be the main cause for error ?

```
StringRequest accessTokenRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, oauthConfig.getTokenEndPointUrl(), new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

//                Log.e("AccessTokenFromLogin", response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put(OAuthConstants.GRANT_TYPE, "password");
                params.put(OAuthConstants.USERNAME, userEmail);
                params.put(OAuthConstants.PASSWORD, userPassword);
                return params;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                if (isValid(clientId))
                    params.put(OAuthConstants.CLIENT_ID, clientId);
                if (isValid(clientSecret))
                    params.put(OAuthConstants.CLIENT_SECRET, clientSecret);
                if (isValid(scope))
                    params.put(OAuthConstants.SCOPE, scope);

                Log.e("LoginActivity",clientId+" "+clientSecret+" "+scope);
                return params;
            }
        };

        Volley.newRequestQueue(this, hurlStack).add(accessTokenRequest);
```

Comment: you should check the server documentation for the reason of 400. Nobody knows what does the server think is wrong with your request.

Comment: I am just confused with the `getParams()` and `getHeaders()` body. For oauth2 is it fine ?

Comment: check your request type . you may call post request instead get request .

Comment: Its a POST request only. If I change to GET. I am getting 405 error. @6155031